# How to correctly implement PHPass password hasher with codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, hash, syntax, passwords

I'm struggling to correctly execute a password hash in codeigniter using phpass.
I have added the phpass password hash file to the libraries folder in codeigniter, and now I don't know how to correctly write the statement  `$t_hasher = new PasswordHash(8, FALSE);` ? Can you guys help with the correct syntax?
Here's what I have so far:

```
function passwordTry() 
{
    $this->load->library('PasswordHash', 'null', 'passHash');
    $hasher = new $this->passHash->PasswordHash(8, FALSE);
    $hash = $hasher->HashPassword('abcd');
    echo ($hash);
    }
```

Comment: does it give any error

Comment: it gives -  Class name must be a valid object or a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 $this->load->library('PasswordHash',array('iteration_count_log2' => 8, 'portable_hashes' => FALSE ), 'passHash');
 $secure_password = $this->passHash->CheckPassword($this->input->post('password'),$pass['password']);

echo $secure_password;
```

Comment: this gives Call to a member function HashPassword() on a non-object for the second line.

Comment: @AndrisGauračs what did you pass as argument to Hashpassword

Comment: Ah, it worked. I just had to do $this->load->library('PasswordHash',array(8, FALSE), 'passHash'); and then use the library with the name 'passHash'. Thanks for the help!